# NCLOB Size Limitation while Calling Procedure #148

Tags: hana

While calling Procedure GET_OBJECT_DEFINITION we have the output parameter OBJECT_CREATION_STATEMENT which will return the creation statement for any object passed to procedure.
The result of OBJECT_CREATIOB_STATEMENT is truncated to 1008 chars. We don't have option to limit the LOB Column Size.

Comment: I guess your question is about a database issue. What database software is it?

Comment: If it's about HANA, see the answer of SAP expert Lars Breddeman "GET_OBJECT_DEFINITION is an internal HANA package. It's not supported externally nor is it documented." (https://answers.sap.com/questions/261401/getobjectdefinition---documentation-and-value-extr.html)

Comment: Tag changed to HANA